# Send Jupiter swap tx to blockchain

Tags: python, transaction, api, swap, jupiter

I'm trying to use Jupiter API to swap tokens via python, and i used basically same code it's been around in this forum, which is:

> swap_instruction = swap_tx_response.json()["swapTransaction"]
>
> raw_tx =
> solders.transaction.VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(swap_instruction))
>
> signature =
> keypair.sign_message(solders.message.to_bytes_versioned(raw_tx.message))
>
> signed_tx =
> solders.transaction.VersionedTransaction.populate(raw_tx.message,
> [signature]) encoded_tx =
> base64.b64encode(bytes(signed_tx)).decode('utf-8')
>
> headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" } data = { "jsonrpc":
> "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "sendTransaction", "params": [ encoded_tx, {
> "skipPreflight": True, "preflightCommitment": "finalized", "encoding":
> "base64", "maxRetries": None, "minContextSlot": None } ] } tx_response
> = httpx.post("rpc_url", headers=headers, json=data)

I'm also running custom "helius RPC" as rpc to send my txs, and i'm finding the problem that some transactions confirm correctly, but others directly doesn't go through the blockchain, showing "no data" in explorer, like this one:

https://solscan.io/tx/2QLTN9mAP9qWR3zQkprPM8k24WpLfi9DoF3qU1E78NBhWpBLrxe7qyVSoL1rB4kYadvpv9Q83NxVEcHHQ7UjSDJV

I don't know what could be causing this as im a bit o a noob on solana, so help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no transaction data, then your transaction was never actually executed and included in a block.

Considering the difficulties around landing transactions recently due to priority fees, you may simply need to add some priority fees to your transactions when targeting mainnet-beta.

More information about priority fees at https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-change-compute-budget-fee-priority-for-a-transaction